# multiple function selectors when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I'm still learning how to write functions..

I want to be able to click on an item, and it will add onto a function

```
<a href='#' onclick="play('url1')">Item 1</a>
<a href='#' onclick="play('url2')">Item 2</a>
<a href='#' onclick="play('url3')">Item 3</a>
```

So if I'm trying to access any of these items, one, two or even all three at the same time, how do I call it into a function if I have something like this

```
function play(url_src){

}
```

src would only be using one item at a time? is there an array associated to this?

do I have to do something like this

```
function play(url_src[]){

}
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to build an array? So if the user clicks item 1 the array will contain {url1} and if the user then clicks on item2 the array will be {url1, url2}?

Comment: `function play(url_src){` is to pass one parameter - it could be array however you passing string in your example

Comment: `or even all three at the same time` What do you mean by this? are you going to click all the link at the same time !

Comment: its an example. if I click one, then it will play one item. But if I have 2 or 3 items clicked, all that have been clicked, should be playing at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your parameter an array:

```
<a href='#' onclick="play(['url1', 'url2'])">Item 4</a>
```

And parse it as such:

```
function play(url_src){
  if (!(url_src instanceof Array)) {
    url_src = [url_src];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < url_src.length; i++) {
    url = url_src[i];

    // Play each url.
  }
}
```

I use the `if` statement on the second line to account for the parameter not being an array, like so:

```
<a href='#' onclick="play('url1')">Item 5</a>
```

Comment: This seems logical. But I was wondering if I'm trying to click item 1 and item 2, each different urls. Would I have to set up another function to capture those two and put it into an array? And then send that array into the `function play(url_src){..}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could either define a new function as mentioned or try `onclick="play('url1');play('url2')"`